# Rich console UI

Tags: java, ui, cli

There are bunch of console programs and especially games using full redraw (not sure ho this correctly named) of console window.

For example, look at output of linux `top` program -> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Top_program.jpg

it doesn't just write text line by line all the time making the whole output oh thousands lines, but every second clears the screen and prints updated information.

Or another example of `Apache Geronimo`: during startup, it prints to console progressbar -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS8uR.jpg

My question is, how to reach the same result using Java?

Comment: [Control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) like carriage return and [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Support for these varies between various terminal emulators.

Comment: The word you are looking for is [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) - a library for positioning and printing the cursor at specific spots on the screen.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321308/ and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

[Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) does this.

> Lanterna is a Java library allowing you to write easy semi-graphical user interfaces in a text-only environment, very similar to the C library curses but with more functionality.